# Table of contents generator for GitHub markdown

Tags: windows, markdown, github

I am looking for a script/program (Windows 7, no Cygwin or VM) or online service that can generate a table of contents for a GitHub-flavored markdown file.

[Example](https://github.com/thlorenz/doctoc):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) the `-f markdown_github` and `-toc` flags and a suitable output format.

Pandoc is Free, Cross Platform & I personally have used it on Linux, **Windows 7** and Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea for [Generate table of contents with links for GitHub markdown win pandoc](http://superuser.com/q/909755/116475)?

Comment: @karel Thanks for pointing out & link - edited all 4.